# How many samples do we need to conclude that the mean of one random variable is greater

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Suppose $X, Y$ are random variable taking values in $[0, 1]$. At each step we can decide to collect samples from either $X$ or $Y$, or decide to stop collecting samples and declare that one of them have greater mean.

Is there a way to make decisions so that for any distributions of $X, Y$ constructed by adversary(But $E(X) \neq E(Y)$), the probability we make a mistake is upper bounded by some specified $\gamma$?

And of course, the fewer samples in expectation the better

Comment: Tight bounds: $Var(X), Var(Y)\leq \frac 1 4$, so $Var(X-Y)\le 1$. Apply CLT to samples from $X-Y$ combined with the last inequality.

Comment: @A.S.: I presume you mean to take an equal number of samples from each of $X,Y$. But I thought it would be better to sample more from the distribution that seems to have a larger variance.

Comment: @user I didn't think of that - the adaptive algorithm indeed would be more efficient though the exact analysis would be a a bit hairier. Write it up!

Comment: @A.S.: I really don't know how exactly to go about it! For discrete distributions we can't simply use the sample standard deviation because it could be zero and we would never sample that distribution again. So I don't know what to use then..